# sum rows in column

Tags: sql

Please assist me. I've been attempting to calculate the sum of all rows in the  **WOR_est_total_hours** column, and all in the **cub_total_erect_hours** column that share a common **ID**. However, I keep encountering errors such as *"is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."* or *"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."*  Please refer to the data in the provided image and the query example below. I have omitted several columns from my select statement to simplify the question for this forum. Due to the involvement of numerous tables in this query, I have become quite confused.

```
SELECT WOR.[id],
   [request_number]               AS [Request Number],
   WOR.[create_date],
   WOR.[modify_date],
   cub.total_erect_hours          AS cub_total_erect_hours,
   COALESCE(mpp.total_hours, 0 )
   + COALESCE(leg.total_hours, 0)
   + COALESCE(cub.total_hours, 0) AS WOR_est_total_hours
FROM   [dbo].[work_order_request] WOR
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[workorder] WO
          ON WOR.[id] = WO.[wor_id]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[wor_type] WT
           ON WOR.[wor_type_id] = WT.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[status] S
          ON WOR.[workorderrequest_status_id] = S.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[work_scope] WS
          ON WOR.[work_class] = WS.[id]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[workflow] WF
           ON WOR.[workflow_id] = WF.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[person] CP
          ON WOR.[contact_user_id] = CP.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[person] RP
          ON WOR.[requested_by_user_id] = RP.[id]
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [work_order_systems_concat]
                ON WOR.[id] =
                   [work_order_systems_concat].[work_order_request_id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[project] P
          ON WOR.[project_id] = P.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[organization] O
          ON P.[organization_id] = O.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[construction_work_package] CWP
          ON WOR.[construction_work_package_id] = CWP.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[internal_work_package] IWP
          ON WOR.[internal_work_package] = IWP.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[request_comment] RC1
          ON ( WOR.[id] = RC1.[work_order_request_id] )
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[request_comment] RC2
          ON ( WOR.[id] = RC2.[work_order_request_id]
               AND ( RC1.[create_date] < RC2.[create_date]
                      OR ( RC1.[create_date] = RC2.[create_date]
                           AND RC1.[id] < RC2.[id] ) ) )
   LEFT JOIN dbo.cubic_meter_workorder_request_calculations_est_hours cub
          ON cub.wor_id = wo.wor_id
   LEFT JOIN dbo.leg_footage_workorder_request_calculations_est_hours leg
          ON leg.wor_id = wo.wor_id
   LEFT JOIN dbo.mpp_workorder_request_calculations_est_hours mpp
          ON mpp.wor_id = wo.wor_id
   LEFT JOIN dbo.usergroup ug
          ON ug.id = wor.scaffolding_contractor_usergroup_id
   LEFT JOIN dbo.estimate e
          ON wo.wor_id = e.work_order_request_id
WHERE  WO.[parent_workorder_id] IS NULL
   AND [request_number] != 'Draft'
   AND RC2.[id] IS NULL
   AND e.parent_estimate_id IS NULL
   AND wor.parent_work_order_request_id IS NULL
   AND wor.id IN ( 8293, 8342, 8343, 8344,
                   8396, 8396, 8399 )
```

[image]

Comment: The query you’ve provided doesn’t include any aggregate functions or subqueries so I assume it is not the one that is giving the errors you mention? If you do have aggregate functions in your SELECT list then all the columns in the SELECT list that aren’t aggregated also have to appear in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @NickW let use column **cub_total_erect_hours** as an example I added this code  `(select sum(cub.total_erect_hours)  from cubic_meter_workorder_request_calculations_est_hours cub group by cub.wor_id) as cub_total_erect_hours2,`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm, and [mcve].

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLBLT.png

Comment: @ATL-JP You can't do an inline subquery like that. It has to be a correlated subquery or return a scalar. That is google-able. If you provide sample data with a minimum reproducible example people will provide a working query.

Comment: LEFT JOIN the subquery instead.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all information to your question as text. Don’t add information in comments. Update your question to show sample data for your source tables, the result you are trying to achieve and the single, best, SQL statement you’ve managed to write - all as editable text

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work! It is a simple Sum and Group By, but because I work with too many Select columns and made mistakes along the way. What I did was comment out all my select columns and do one calculation column at a time, gradually adding in the rest of the columns. Below is my final query. Thank you all for your comments.

```
SELECT WOR.[id],
   [request_number]                    AS [Request Number],
   WOR.[create_date],
   WOR.[modify_date],
   Sum(cub.total_erect_hours)          AS cub_total_erect_hours,
   Sum(COALESCE(mpp.total_hours, 0 )
       + COALESCE(leg.total_hours, 0)
       + COALESCE(cub.total_hours, 0)) AS WOR_est_total_hours
  FROM   [dbo].[work_order_request] WOR
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[workorder] WO
          ON WOR.[id] = WO.[wor_id]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[wor_type] WT
           ON WOR.[wor_type_id] = WT.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[status] S
          ON WOR.[workorderrequest_status_id] = S.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[work_scope] WS
          ON WOR.[work_class] = WS.[id]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[workflow] WF
           ON WOR.[workflow_id] = WF.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[person] CP
          ON WOR.[contact_user_id] = CP.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[person] RP
          ON WOR.[requested_by_user_id] = RP.[id]
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [work_order_systems_concat]
                ON WOR.[id] =
                   [work_order_systems_concat].[work_order_request_id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[project] P
          ON WOR.[project_id] = P.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[organization] O
          ON P.[organization_id] = O.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[construction_work_package] CWP
          ON WOR.[construction_work_package_id] = CWP.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[internal_work_package] IWP
          ON WOR.[internal_work_package] = IWP.[id]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[request_comment] RC1
          ON ( WOR.[id] = RC1.[work_order_request_id] )
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[request_comment] RC2
          ON ( WOR.[id] = RC2.[work_order_request_id]
               AND ( RC1.[create_date] < RC2.[create_date]
                      OR ( RC1.[create_date] = RC2.[create_date]
                           AND RC1.[id] < RC2.[id] ) ) )
   LEFT JOIN dbo.cubic_meter_workorder_request_calculations_est_hours cub
          ON cub.wor_id = wo.wor_id
   LEFT JOIN dbo.leg_footage_workorder_request_calculations_est_hours leg
          ON leg.wor_id = wo.wor_id
   LEFT JOIN dbo.mpp_workorder_request_calculations_est_hours mpp
          ON mpp.wor_id = wo.wor_id
   LEFT JOIN dbo.usergroup ug
          ON ug.id = wor.scaffolding_contractor_usergroup_id
   LEFT JOIN dbo.estimate e
          ON wo.wor_id = e.work_order_request_id
  WHERE  WO.[parent_workorder_id] IS NULL
   AND [request_number] != 'Draft'
   AND RC2.[id] IS NULL
   AND e.parent_estimate_id IS NULL
   AND wor.parent_work_order_request_id IS NULL
   AND wor.id IN ( 8293, 8342, 8343, 8344,
                   8396, 8396, 8399 )
  GROUP  BY WOR.[id],
      [request_number],
      WOR.[create_date],
      WOR.[modify_date]
```